# Actionbar spinner text color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I'm trying to change the text color of the spinner in action bar. I want to change the text color that appears on the actionbar without changing the color the dropdown items

here is a pic describes what I mean

[image]

Comment: add custom layout to action bar  by this way you can change selected text color without changing list of text color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set simple array adapter to spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> customeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listview_array);
actSpinner.setAdapter(customeAdapter);
```

Then you can change text color like that

```
actSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            CheckedTextView textView= (CheckedTextView)arg1;
             textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            System.err.println("arg2="+ arg2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

OR you can customize your action bar with spinner

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.spineer_view_layout, null);
    Spinner actSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_action_bar);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(view);
    MyCustomeAdapter customeAdapter = new MyCustomeAdapter(this, listview_array);
    actSpinner.setAdapter(customeAdapter);
    actSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout )arg1;
             TextView textView =(TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
             textView .setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            System.err.println("arg2="+ arg2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

spinner_action_bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_action_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is getView of Custome Adpater

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.adapter_offer_item_layout, null);
        holder.descritpionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.descritpionTextView.setText(listview_array[position]);

    return convertView;
}
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView descritpionTextView;
}
```

adapter_offer_item_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```